# py2exe in C:\Windows\System32 on 64-bit Windows

Tags: python, backup, py2exe

I'm trying to run [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) under Windows 8 x64 which is written in python and apparently uses py2exe to create a Windows executable. It's written at their website that the Visual C++ 2008 redistributable is required which I installed (x86 and x64).

Now, when running `rdiff-backup.exe -V` from any directory, it gives the correct output (the version used): `rdiff-backup 1.2.8`. I want to use it with [JBackpack](http://www.nongnu.org/jbackpack/) which is a Java-based GUi and requires `rdiff-backup.exe` to be present in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory so I copied it there but running it from this directory throws the following error.

```
C:\Windows\System32>rdiff-backup.exe -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\boot_common.py", line 92, in <module>
ImportError: No module named linecache
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<install zipextimporter>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named zipextimporter
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "rdiff-backup", line 20, in <module>
ImportError: No module named rdiff_backup.Main
```

What strikes me is that it is running from a different dirctory (unfortunatly one can't change its path in JBackpack).

I also downloaded the dll-package for p2exe which is provided on their and rdiff-backup's website but this doesn't help neither. So, why isn't it working in the `System32` directory and is there a workaround?

Comment: I suspect that either `rdiff-backup.exe` may need to go into `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Comment: You're suspecting correctly, it is working when put there. I was just about to accept your answer, unfortunately you deleted it :-) Just put it back and I'll accept it. Plus I found the Wikipedia article on [WOW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) and it all makes sense now.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was right so thought it might be better as a comment.  I've undeleted the answer and added a bit more info, should anyone else have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `rdiff-backup.exe` into `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.  You are experiencing Windows on Windows which causes [path redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64#Registry_and_file_system) for 32-bit processes running on a 64-bit OS.